# How to share a dataframe in stack overflow

Tags: r

I have lots of questions I need help answering in R, but the only way I know how to share my dataframe is to post a screenshot of it, which isn't user-friendly. Can someone please tell me a more appropriate way of sharing my dataframe whenever I need help with R on Stack Overflow?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: use `dput()` for your dfs.